# How can I retract erroneous downvotes after five minutes have passed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I just noticed a newuser who has 4 rep.  I was trying to figure out how that's possible and I realized they might have +5 for one upvote and -2 for one downvote. Went to check for that and found *I* downvoted them.

I have no idea how that happened but I'm sure the iPad policy of "interpret half of all scroll swipes as clicks on random loctions" had everything to do with it.  (Web UI via Safari).

Apparently this happened >5 min ago.  I found a shallow pretense to edit the question, but otherwise I or anyone else would be stuck.  Any sane ways to address this?

Comment: Doesn't this apply to upvotes as well?

Answer (score 3):

Edit the question (even if it's trivial) and then remove the upvote. It seems like it's dirty but it is acceptable. You have enough rep to do it.

See [Is there a way to cancel the downvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-the-downvote)